# How to access Azure SQL using a P2S VPN and Azure Active Directory : the login failed. Microsoft SQL Server error 40532

Tags: azure-sql-database

I didn't want to comment on a similar issue which has already been covered on [How to give access to Azure-sql server over p2s vpn for developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68630853/how-to-give-access-to-azure-sql-server-over-p2s-vpn-for-developers), I am essentially following on from that.

I have got point to site VPN configured. I can access SQL Server using the IP address from the virtual network when using SQL Server authentication.

I do have a private endpoint configured using a more friendly name `mydb.privatelink.database.windows.net`. The problem here is that using this with Azure AD authentication means that it is trying to use my public IP which isn't allowed on the SQL Server firewall and disregarding my P2S VPN connection.

I got SQL login working using the tips in the link above, however what I want to get working is Azure AD with MFA. If I use the vnet IP address which works for SQL Server authentication, and select Azure AD authentication with MFA, I get the error

> Cannot open server "10.1.1.x" requested by the login. The login failed. Microsoft SQL server Error 40532.

One of my objectives is to provide connectivity to SQL Server without having to allow the public IP address of several users.

Comment: Hi @learner, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem and I've found a solution for that: you need to update the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) and add an try with your private endpoint IP and the database host name. This way, the authentication using MFA will work fine and you don't need to add your local IP to the database firewall, since it will be using the VPN connection. Example to add to the host file:

10.2.0.8       mydomain.database.windows.net

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot open server "10.1.1.x" requested by the login. The login failed. Microsoft SQL server Error 40532

To solve the above error, you should follow your username with '@servername' (where **Servername is the name of your SQL server**).

In **"Firewalls and virtual networks"** of your SQL server, if you marked **"Deny public network access"** to yes then `you will not be able to access the public IP Address, so set it to No to access public IP Address`.

For more details on the above, kindly refer to the below documentation link given: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings?view=azuresql#deny-public-network-access***